# It's possible to add a multiple regex rule with antdesign?

Tags: regex, validation, antd

I am trying to validate a NIF/NIE in the same input.

I am trying to get an error if the input doesn't match both regex.

```
 <Form.Item
              name="nifnie"
              label="NIF/NIE"
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: "NIF/NIE is mandatory." },
                {
                  pattern:
                    /^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$/i ||
                    /^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$/i,
                  message: "Not a valid format.",
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Input />
            </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 2 patterns, you can write it using a single pattern and an alternation between `[XYZ][0-9]{7}` and `[0-9]{8}` as the rest of both patterns is the same:

```
/^(?:[XYZ][0-9]{7}|[0-9]{8})[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$/i
```

Or

```
new RegExp('^(?:[XYZ][0-9]{7}|[0-9]{8})[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$', 'i')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i'm new to programming and regex patterns are not easy for me.. hehe. You solved my problem :)